# Where is my mistake - offsite request - scrapy

Tags: scrapy

I am trying to solve offsite request bug, where is my mistake?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule

class BestMoviesSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'best_movies'
    allowed_domains = ['imbd.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?groups=top_250&sort=user_rating']

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//h3[@class="lister-item-header"]/a'), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        print(response.url)
```

In VSCode shows me:

```
[scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.imdb.com': <GET https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0111161/>
```

Instead of a list of links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wrong domain, you have:

```
allowed_domains = ['imbd.com']
```

but should be like website domain:

```
allowed_domains = ['imdb.com']
```

you have im**bd**, need to change to im**db**